# Embed Mondrian analysis to report designer 3.9.x

Tags: pentaho

I already built mondrian analysis with mdx query.

Now, i want to embed this analysis to report designer 3.9.x.Could i do that?How?

I'll appreciate for any response...thx

Answer (score 0):

Very basic question! Just right click on the data source in report designer, and add a "Pentaho Analysis" data source.  Tell it where your mondrian schema xml is, and paste the MDX in. Thats it.